# What is the explanation of why does gasoline leaks from a bearing seal but oil does not?

Tags: bearings, seals

[image: Bearing with rubber seal]

The above is a bearing with rubber seal. Such bearing is used in automotive engine. With that rubber seal, the lubricating and cooling oil inside the engine the oil does not leak. But when the oil is replaced with gasoline, the gasoline is leaks. The same case if that engine is filled with water, it does not leak but leaks if the engine is filled with detergent solution. Just incase this information is related: density of oil is 0.8 kg/L, density of gasoline is 0.78 kg/L, density of water is 1 kg/L, while density of detergent solution I have no idea.

My question is, what is the explanation that gasoline and detergent solution are leak with that rubber seal but lubricating oil and water are not?

Comment: surface tension

Comment: @jsotola I see. That make sense. Indeed, surface tension of detergent solution is lower than surface tension of pure water.

Answer (score 0):

Because different fluids have other characteristics which require different types of seals.

In the case of gas, you should be considering capillary action of the different fluids.

Comment: I guessed soo, too. But what is specifically? Especially I am curious about the gasoline and the detergent solution leak with that seal, but not water and oil. What fluid property plays in that role?